# Как побороть ошибку 504 Gateway Timeout (time out)?

Tags: php, exec

Есть общий скрипт:

```
<?php

$connect=new mysqli("localhost","","","");
$connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

clear_table("a",$connect);  
clear_table("b",$connect);
clear_table("c",$connect);
...

include_once 'data_new.php';
exec('php data_new.php');    //insert данных в foreach

include_once 'data_old.php';
exec('php data_old.php');   //insert данных в foreach

include_once 'data_fut.php';
exec('php data_fut.php');    //insert данных в foreach


function clear_table($table, $connect){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$table;
    $connect->query($sql);
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE ".$table." AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
    $connect->query($sql);   
}

?>
```

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы каждый `clear_table` и каждый `exec` выполнялся поочередно, а то при запуске выдает ошибку (`Ошибка 504 Gateway Timeout (time out) nginx`) ?

Comment: сделать 3 скрипта и в каждом ссылку на следующий.

Comment: @Ипатьев, как именно дать ссылку подскажите пжл

Comment: <a href=script>следующий</a>

Comment: @Ипатьев, я хочу, чтобы скрипт обрабатывал все сам, а здесь думаю надо потом нажимать в ручную...

Comment: Можно использовать внешние отладчики. XDebug, например. Совсем замечательно использовать IDE, который умеет работать с отладчиком - тогда будет прямо как в Visual Studio и подобных. PHPStorm умеет всё, но платный.

Comment: @Амирхон подобного результата можно добиться путём передачи гет-параметров в скрипт.

Comment: Вы сначала определитесь, "сам" или "пошагово".

Comment: @Ипатьев, пошагово конечно, я под "все сам", имел виду, что скрипт без моего участие пошагово выполнял)

Comment: @Амирхон я напишу вам пример, но проверить у меня не на чём - самостоятельно сможете по его аналогу дописать ваш код?

Comment: @Эдуард, думаю да, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поочерёдно выполнять разные блоки `case'ов`, передавая в `switch()` GET-параметры, и в каждом `case'е` выполнять перенаправление на следующий по порядку `case`. Теоретически, этот код должен запускаться при клике по ссылке "Запуск", и останавливаться после выполнения последнего блока `case: 3`:

```
$connect=new mysqli("localhost","","","");
$connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$k = isset($_GET['k']) ? abs($_GET['k']) : 0;

switch ($k) {
    case 1:
        clear_table("a", $connect);
        // include_once 'data_new.php';
        exec('php data_new.php');    //insert данных в foreach
        header('Refresh:0; url=?k=' . ++$k);
        break;

    case 2:
        clear_table("b",$connect);
        // include_once 'data_old.php';
        exec('php data_old.php');   //insert данных в foreach
        header('Refresh:0; url=?k=' . ++$k);
        break;

    case 3:
        clear_table("c",$connect);
        // include_once 'data_fut.php';
        exec('php data_fut.php');    //insert данных в foreach
        header('Refresh:0; url=' . basename(__FILE__));
        break;

    default:
        echo '<a href="?k=1">Запуск</a>';
        break;
}


function clear_table($table, $connect){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ".$table;
    $connect->query($sql);
    $sql = "ALTER TABLE ".$table." AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
    $connect->query($sql);   
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто убрать строчки с exec() (или include, на выбор)

Тогда этот код перестанет выполнять каждый скрипт по два раза и станет работать значительно быстрее.

Плюс, если там вставки в цикле, то заключить их в [транзакции](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/insert#multiple)

Answer (score -1):

> Ошибка 504 Gateway Timeout (time out) nginx

В вашем php скрипте нужно увеличить время выполнения, это можно сделать следующим образом

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0); // 0 Без-конечно или же другое время в секундах
```

Раз у вас ругается NGINX нужно править его конфиг, на ограничения `ngixn` влияют следующие настройки, это с учетом что у вас за ним стоит `apache` а не что-то вроде `PHP-FPM`

```
# Где-то в nginx.conf - файле
proxy_connect_timeout 600; 
proxy_send_timeout 600; 
proxy_read_timeout 600; 
send_timeout 600;
```